# Fake $0=1$ integral examples.

Tags: calculus, integration, fake-proofs

The classic "proof" that says 0=1 with integration by parts is this:
$$\int\frac{1}{x}\,dx=x\frac{1}{x}-\int -\frac 1{x^2}x\,dx=1+\int \frac1x\,dx.$$
However the wikipedia article gives another one of these integrands, 
$$\int \frac{1}{x\log x}\,dx$$
My question is:

What integrands can be integrated by parts in this way to give a fallacious proof that $1=0$?

Comment: And please don't do something like $$\int \frac 2x$$

Comment: If you can provide that wikipedia article, it would be better.

Comment: Every integrand has this property.

Comment: @Micah $$\int e^x=xe^x-\int xe^x$$ does not?

Comment: Yeah, this property is completely unsurprising: generic antiderivative gives you a constant to play around with afterwards.

Comment: @DanUznanski I understand that the fallacy is reliant on a certain constant, but I am wondering if the constant is ommited if a new number could be added to the equation

Comment: @MathN00b Yes, $$\int f(x) dx = c + \int f(x) dx$$ for any integrable $f$ and any $c$

Comment: @DanUznanski But I am asking for an apparent constant that appears in the equation with INTEGRATION BY PARTS ONLY.

Comment: Nope.  Actually, the degree of freedom you get from integrals is so important that in some situations it can force additional solutions to a problem.  Take for instance solutions to the differential equation $y'' - 2y' + y = 0$.  Since the roots of $u^2 - 2u + 1=0$ are 1 and 1, $y(x) = c_1e^x$ is one solution.  But there should be *two* linearly independent solutions, because we need to integrate $y''$ twice.  Turns out that $y(x) = c_1e^x+c_2xe^x$ is the full answer.

Comment: @MathN00b: No, but that's just because you didn't pick the right $u$ and $v$. Note that $\int e^x \, dx = \int e^{e^x} (e^{-e^x} e^x \, dx) = 1 + \int e^x\, dx$...

Comment: @DanUznanski I think you are misinterpreting the problem. I want to see different kinds of integrals that when Integration of parts is done once, the integral appears on both sides of the equation as $\int f(x)=1+\int f(x)$

Comment: @Micah If you do claim that it is true, can you provide a proof of that statement?

Comment: Another use of these examples: to emphasize to calculus students not to forget the ${}+C$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens when we can write $\int f(x) \, dx$ as $\int u \, dv$ where $uv=1$: then, when we integrate by parts, the $uv$ term will be constant (and so the $\int v \, du$ term must be the same as the $\int u \, dv$ term).

But if $uv=1$, then $dv=d(1/u)=-du/u^2$, and so this is equivalent to requiring that
$$
f(x) \, dx = u(-du/u^2)=-du/u=-d(\ln u) \, .
$$

That is, we can build this kind of fake proof for any $f$ we like: we just need to take $u$ so that $\ln u$ is an antiderivative of $-f$. (Of course, that means that building the proof is tantamount to performing the integral...)

For example, we can integrate $x^2$ by parts, letting $u=e^{-x^3/3}$ and $dv=e^{x^3/3} x^2 \, dx$. Then $v=e^{x^3/3}$ and $du = -x^2e^{-x^3/3} \, dx$ and so

$$
\int x^2 \, dx = \int e^{-x^3/3} (e^{x^3/3} x^2 \, dx)= e^{-x^3/3}e^{x^3/3} - \int e^{x^3/3}(-x^2e^{-x^3/3} \, dx)=1+\int x^2 \, dx \, .
$$

Of course, this is unlikely to fool anyone, because the choice of $u$ and $v$ looks so unnatural. Perhaps the real answer to your question is "whenever this choice of $u$ and $v$ looks like a good idea." But "looking like a good idea" isn't particularly well-defined. In general, non-contrived-looking versions of this will occur when the antiderivative of $f$ is an explicit logarithm, meaning we can define $u$ without introducing a seemingly extraneous exponential. Note that your two examples are the derivative of $\ln x$ and the derivative of $\ln \ln x$; [the other common function to use in this kind of fake proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/424854/1-0-by-integration-by-parts-of-tanx) is $\tan x$, which is the derivative of $\ln \cos x$.