# Fake proof that $\frac{e^x-1}{e^x+1}=e^x$, via integrating $\operatorname{sech} x$ in two ways

Tags: integration, trigonometry, exponential-function, fake-proofs

We start with the integral:
$$\int \text{sech}(x)dx$$

---

**Method 1**
\begin{align}
\int \text{sech}(x)dx & = \int\frac{2}{e^x+e^{-x}}dx \\
&= \int\frac{2e^x}{e^{2x}+1}dx
\end{align}
Using the substitution $u=e^x$,
\begin{align}
\int \text{sech}(x)dx & = \int\frac{2}{u^2+1}du \\
&= 2\text{ arctan}(u)+c \\
&= 2\text{ arctan}(e^x)+c
\end{align}

---

**Method 2**
\begin{align}
\int \text{sech}(x)dx & = \int\frac{\text{cosh}(x)}{\text{cosh}^2(x)}dx \\
& = \int\frac{\text{cosh}(x)}{\text{sinh}^2(x)+1}dx
\end{align}
Using the substitution $u=\text{sinh}(x)$,
\begin{align}
\int \text{sech}(x)dx & = \int\frac{1}{u^2+1}du \\
&= \text{arctan}(\text{sinh}(x))+c \\
&= 2\text{ arctan}(\text{tanh}(\frac{x}{2}))+c \\
&= 2\text{ arctan}(\frac{e^x-1}{e^x+1})+c
\end{align}

---

Thus, we obtain:

> $$\frac{e^x-1}{e^x+1}=e^x$$

However, I see no reason why they are equal. Did I do something wrong in the calculation?

Comment: Because $2\arctan\left(\frac{e^x-1}{e^x+1}\right)=2\left(\arctan(e^x)-\frac\pi4\right)=2\arctan(e^x)+C'$

Comment: Related: ["I can't remember a fallacious proof involving integrals and trigonometric identities"](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1114628/409) with the classic "proof" of $0=1$ via integrating $\sin 2x$ in two ways.

Comment: It is easy to conflate the $+C$ as the same constant whenever you compute an indefinite integral different ways. You are really specifying a(n equivalence) class of functions--those that differ by a constant--and so you can only conclude your two results are in the same class of functions, not that they are equal.

Comment: This particular occurs when dealing with trigonometric integrals because there are many hidden identities that can allow us to express the result in different ways.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Because $2\arctan\left(\frac{e^x-1}{e^x+1}\right)=2\left(\arctan(e^x)-\frac\pi4\right)=2\arctan(e^x)+C'$.

The results differ by a constant.

Comment: Can you further explain why $\text{arctan}(\frac{e^x-1}{e^x+1})$ can be transformed into $\text{arctan}(e^x)-\pi/4$?

Comment: Try expanding $\tan(\arctan(e^x)-\frac{\pi}4)$ by sum of angle